# Checkbox color darkens on hover

Tags: css, accent-color

I have changed the color of my checkboxes when they are checked to not be the default light blue using the following CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  accent-color: var(--red);
}
```

I tried using the :hover pseudo-selector however it still darkens it.

```css
:root {
  --red: #ee5d5a;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  accent-color: var(--red);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover {
  accent-color: var(--red);
}
```

```html
<input id="two" type="checkbox" checked>General
```

Comment: The hover effect is good and accessible in my opinion. I'd say your choices are to suck it up with what the UA gives you, or [make your own checkbox from scratch](https://moderncss.dev/pure-css-custom-checkbox-style/)

Comment: P.S use a label for inputs instead of a text node `<label for="two">General</label>`

Comment: Interesting that in Chrome apparently "setting" the hover state for the element via dev tools, does _not_ appear to trigger this - it needs a "real" hover with my mouse, to see the actual darkening happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add This you get the exact color which you use for your default checkbox

```
input[type=checkbox]:hover{ filter: brightness(1.5); }
```